# Angular2 :How to make a movable svg object with hammer.js?

Tags: svg, typescript, angular, hammer.js

i'm Working on an angular2 app, and i'm using hammer.js to make movable a simple rectangle svg object in the view of my component , the methode i uses consists on using the "pan action " of hammer which gives me the x and y position of every deplacing clich mouvement , and i'm affecting thos x and y into the x and y attribtes of my svg rectangle , the problem is that this affectation is not done even i'm seeing in the console the value of x and y of the action ,

any idea to pass the value of depalcement into the svg element postion ???

this is my code :

the view:

```
<div>
        <svg class="simulation">
            <rect id="test1" x="{{NX}}" y="{{NY}}" height="150" width="200"
                  style="stroke:#EC9A20;stroke-width: 15; fill: none"/>

        </svg>
    </div>
```

and the TS.file :

```
 export class ContentComponent implements AfterViewInit{
 static hammerInitialized = false;
    public NX:any ;
    public NY:any ;

    ngAfterViewInit():any {
            console.log('in ngAfterViewInit');
            if (!ContentComponent.hammerInitialized) {

                var myElement = document.getElementById('test1');//indiquer ici l'element
                var animation = new Hammer(myElement);

                animation.get('pan').set({direction:Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL})

                animation.on("panleft panright panup pandown tap press",
                                    (ev):any => {

                                        myElement.textContent = ev.type +" gesture detected.";
                                        console.log(ev);


                                        this.NX=ev.center.x;
                                       console.log("NX="+this.NX) // this show successfully the value of the action movement NX
                                        this.NY=ev.center.y;
                                        console.log("NY="+this.NY) // this show successfully the value of the action movement NY
                                    }

                );

                ContentComponent.hammerInitialized = true;
            }

            else {
                console.log('hammer already initialised');
             }
console.log("NX="+this.NX); //here it shows me that NX is undefined
console.log("NY="+this.NY)  //undefined too

    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with typescript, but I'm going to go against my suspicion and suggest that it looks like the fat arrow is producing the wrong this.  Not sure why that would be so, but all things being equal, I can't see any other cause.  Have you looked at myElement.NX or myElement.NY to see if your values have turned up there?

Comment: As for setting the x and y on the element, you can do that directly without the angular wrapper (from inside the event), but that's probably not what you want.  Make sure you check to see that your angular binding is working as expected too. :)

Comment: probably it may help me , to set x and y from inside the event , but how can i do it when those x and y are attributes of my svg rectangle ,defined in the html file of my component  and which communicate only and directly with the TS part of the code and not the js

Comment: Are methods on document elements not available in typescript?  Such as `myElement.setAttribute("x", ev.center.x);  myElement.setAttribute("y", ev.center.y);`?  I was assuming you wouldn't want to do it that way, but it should work.

Comment: in angular 2 the ts part and the html are separated and communicate with injected values , by the way i cannot set "x" directly from ts , i should alwyas create methods which recuper values from html and create references to others declared in my ts and finally inject my ts variables into my html again

Comment: I think the 'this' in the animation handler is not the same as the 'this' of your component. Try to create a var self=this at the beginning of ngAfterViewInit and use the self.NX and self.NY in the animation handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that worked by not passing the hammer function as a static param

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //reference à l'element svg

                var myElement = document.getElementById('idsimulation');
                var actionHammer = new Hammer(myElement);

            //action pan
                actionHammer.get('pan').set({direction:Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL});
                        //actionHammer.on("panleft panright panup pandown tap press",hammer);
                        //actionHammer.on('pan',hammer);


                actionHammer.on('pan',ev => {
                    //console.log(ev);
                    console.log("X=" + ev.center.x);
                    console.log("Y=" + ev.center.x);

                    this.ParamService.dormant.X0 = (ev.center.x) - 200; //170
                    this.ParamService.dormant.Y0 = (ev.center.y) - 190; //150


                    // myElement.setAttribute("x", ev.center.x+200);
                    // myElement.setAttribute("y", ev.center.y+270);
                    });
            //action pinch
                actionHammer.get('pinch').set({enable:true});
                actionHammer.on('pinch',ev =>{
                    console.log(ev);
                })


    }
```